# Reconstruct array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have thousands of lines of `Javascript` code like this:

```
var myCoordinates = [

    new google.maps.LatLng(11.11111,22.222222),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.33333,44.444444),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.55555,66.666666),

    //thousands of lines
];
```

I need to format code above to this without whitespaces *(a.k.a to string I could copy to my PHP code)*:

---

```
[["lat"=>11.11111,"lng"=>22.22222],["lat"=>33.33333,"lng"=>44.44444],["lat"=>55.55555,"lng"=>66.66666],/*etc*/];
```

---

**What I've tried and failed:**

```
document.getElementById('format-submit').onclick = function() {

    var textareaValue = document.getElementById('format-textarea').value;

    var findA = 'var myCoordinates = ';
    var rA = new RegExp( findA, 'g' );
    var resultA = textareaValue.replace( rA, '' );

    //I get this error on this line:

    //Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /new google.maps.LatLng(/: Unterminated group

    //              |
    //              V

    var findB = 'new google.maps.LatLng(';
    var rB = new RegExp(findB, 'g');
    var resultB = resultA.replace(rB, '["lat" => ');

    var findC = '),';
    var rC = new RegExp(findC, 'g');
    var resultC  = resultB.replace(rC, '],');

    var findD = ')';
    var rD = new RegExp(findD, 'g');
    var finalResult  = resultC.replace(rD, ']');

    textareaValue = finalResult;
};
```

---

Speed or performance is not an issue, I just need to:

1. Copy first `JS` code to textarea
2. Format it when button is pressed
3. Replace textarea value with formatted code
4. Copy it
5. Paste it to my code

---

**Question:**

How to replace part of string which has all kinds of letters, special characters etc in it?

*(probable cause of error, right?)*

Comment: Regular expressions have a specific syntax, sending strings with characters that have special meaning in them to the RegExp constructor will result in an error. You should just use the string itself (e.g. `resultB.replace(findC, '],');`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```js
document.getElementById('format-submit').onclick = function() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('format-textarea');

    textarea.value = textarea.value
        .replace(/^[^\[]+/,'')
        .replace(/^.*\(([\d.]+),([\d.]+)\)(,)?$/gm,'["lat" => $1, "lng" => $2]$3')
        .replace(/\s+/g,'');
};
```

```html
<textarea id="format-textarea" rows="7" cols="46">var myCoordinates = [

    new google.maps.LatLng(11.11111,22.222222),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.33333,44.444444),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.55555,66.666666)

];</textarea><br>
<input type="button" id="format-submit" value="Format textarea">
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. **Could you modify your answer to also remove all spaces?**

Comment: @Solo Edited, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Almost. Is there a way to remove **all** the spaces? Around `=>` and `commas` as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this code this will give you what you want i guess

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
var myCoordinates = [

    new google.maps.LatLng(11.11111,22.222222),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.33333,44.444444),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.55555,66.666666),

    //thousands of lines
];
var fullJson = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myCoordinates.length; i++) {
    var temp = {};
    var pos = myCoordinates[i];
    temp['lat'] = pos.lat();
    temp['lng'] = pos.lng();
    fullJson.push(temp);
} 
var str_json = JSON.stringify(fullJson);
$.post('index.php', str_json, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($str_json);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```